# Google Sheets: Repeat SUMIF over multiple columns with different sum ranges and criteria

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

Here is my example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wRvpRufL4JlY8AprwHCZvvXlVijg2u2Y2jG-6b62FEA/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

This is a simple stock register sheet, where I am keeping stock in "Stock Sheet". I am trying to add all the out movement in "Out" column. So It should basic search for particular product like "Prod 1" and look for it in "Movement" sheet and "Prod" sheet and sum all the movement. However in "Prod" sheet there are multiple columns where It can be present. So I need to check columns "Raw 1", "Raw 2" and add quantity in each.

In simple terms, in Prod sheet, products being used will sum in "Out" and produced in "In" column.

Thank you in advance. I can do this by adding SUMIF multiple times for each column, I am trying to find more efficient way to do it as this sheet will expand a lot and single formula will then go in multiple lines.

Comment: Please post data rather than a link to a file. The purpose is to help you and future visitors with a similar problem. They(/we) should recognize the problem from the post. Also. Excel’s not Google sheets. Choose your tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect all data in a new tab (Prod_plus) by

```
=query({Prod!F2:G;Prod!H2:I;Prod!J2:K;Prod!L2:M;Prod!N2:O},"select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1")
```

[image]

and then

```
=SUMIF(Movement!$B$2:$B,A2,Movement!$G$2:$G)+SUMIF(Prod_plus!$A$2:$A,A2,Prod_plus!$B$2:$B)
```

Comment: Got it, thanks.
I will be doing it over multiple production sheets but this is a good point to start